# What are the Visor alternatives?

Tags: terminal, plugins

Visor is a plugin for Terminal.app that allows usage of quake-console-style terminal access. Are there any alternatives to this Terminal.app plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [hotkey window](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/hotkey) in iTerm2 works well for this, but with one catch - it only works if iterm2 is open (it doesn't have to be focused or in the foreground, but it must be running).

Answer (score 6):

Try TotalTerminal (http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/). It's by the author of Visor, but doesn't require SIMBL to function. And it works flawlessly on Lion.

Answer (score 1):

For quickly executing simple commands, [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm) can be an excellent solution. It can execute simple, non-interactive commands without opening a terminal window, or you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd> to have it execute the command in a Terminal/iTerm window.

I think of DTerm as a sort of CLI app launcher, similar to common GUI app launchers like Alfred, Quicksilver, LaunchBar, or even Spotlight.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I always ask [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) to give me the stuff I want, so my **Hotkey** would be

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>i</kbd> this will invoke [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) and select [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com)

[image]

It's more than a keystroke, but Alfred gives me so much power :)